# Xpath expression, format method, using variables outside for loop, Python

Tags: python, string, xpath

I am using xpath and lxml to parse an XML file. I use format to increment the value in the item element, item[{}], so that I can get data from the first element, 2nd, and so on. I loop through based on number of times the //items/item element appears in the XML file, which works. When I get to the last item in the tuple I increase z by 1.

QUESTION:
I can't figure how to assign the tuple value outside this for loop, and still use format to increase the value of z. If I define the tuple outside the for loop, z always equals 1. It works as shown, but I don't like it.

```
x = 0
y = 1 
z = 1
for field in xrange(1, 3):
        dataFields = \
            (("itemType" , "//items/item[{}]//@itemType".format(z)),
            ("itemClass" , "//items/item[{}]//@itemClass".format(z)),)
    currentData = dataFields[x][y]
    try:
        r = tree.xpath(currentData)[0]
    except:
        r = ""
    f = open(dataOutputFile, 'a')
    f.write(str(r) + "\t")
    f.close()
    x += 1
    if "itemClass" in currentData:
        z += 1
```